# 'this' gets undefined on a callback context

Tags: javascript, node.js

In this scenario I get `this` to be `undefined`:

```
function outside(callback){
    callback()
}

var obj = {
    myProperty: 'john',
  
    f1: function() {
        outside(this.f2)
    },
  
    f2: function() {
        console.log('-->', this.myProperty)
    }
}

obj.f1()
```

How to fix it so `this` in `f2` will refer to `obj`?

Comment: `f1: function() { outside(this.f2.bind(this)) }` or `f1: function() { outside(_ => this.f2()) }`. See docs for [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bind for that.
See link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind